# Flutter - setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build using controller in showDialog

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a custom form which includes a colorpicker. The colorpicker is wrapped in a custom class (AppColorpickerFormFieldState) and I use a controller to retrieve the color picked.

For some reasons, I get the following error when I try to open the colorpicker :

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVcKE.png)

Here is the some details about my code (link to the full code at the bottom of this post):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      key: _formKey ,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AppColorpickerFormField(
            controller: colorController,
            defaultColor: defaultColor,
            title: 'Couleur de la lumière'
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The class that is being called:

```
Class AppColorpickerFormFieldState extends State<AppColorpickerFormField> {
  late Color pickerColor;
  late Color currentColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: showColorpicker,
              child: Container( 
                height:50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

The methods that open the colorpicker :

```
void showColorpicker() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Modifier la couleur'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ColorPicker(
              onColorChanged: changeColor,
              pickerColor: pickerColor,
              enableAlpha: false,
              labelTypes: const [],
              hexInputController: widget.controller,
            )
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Valider'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() => currentColor = pickerColor);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Link to the full code app : https://github.com/OtarieElephant/ledpacer.git

I have tried different solutions related to various posts with the same error such as using async, using futureBuilder, etc... but nothing worked. This is my first time developping on Flutter so maybe I just don't understand the way the app is built. I just need to retrieve the color picked on my main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is being triggered by your call to setState in the listener you added to the colorController.  If you change that to the following the error goes away.

```
colorController.addListener(() {
  print('test ${colorController.text}');
});
```

What needs to happen here?

As far as sending data from one Widget back to another Widget, you have lots of options. For example:

a - use a callback method. As an example, ColorPicker has you pass a method named onColorChanged that gets called when the ColorPicker wants to let you know what color was picked.

b - return data through navigation. see https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

c - store the data somewhere that both parts of your code can access

d - use a more advanced state management solution like provider, bloc or riverpod

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It seems to work for the print. My objective is to save the color in my SeptupForm component and display it (as I did for distance and duration controllers that I listen too). 
As you mentionned, there are different ways to achieve this, which one is the "best" ? I wanted to listen controllers and use a setState because I thought this is how we do but it doesnt work for my colorpicker.

Comment: For components that I want to reuse in multiple places in my projects, I like passing "call back functions" as parameters that can send updates. This is usually very flexible with minimal overhead.

For more advanced state management, I'm a fan of bloc. But that's mostly because I'm very familiar with it.

It's probably best to learn to use different solutions so that you can choose the one that makes the most sense for your particular project.